# Checking for duplicates in while typing in input with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have an array like so:

```
$scope.items = [
    {'name': '1'},
    {'name': '2'},
    {'name': '3'},
];
```

Then I have in my template:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in items">
    <input ng-model="x.name" />
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I would go about not allowing duplicate names? For example, if someone typed in the **3rd** input box the number *1*, it wouldn't allow it.

Comment: What does "wouldn't allow" mean? will it fail validation? In any case, you'd have to find duplicates manually on some trigger (e.g. on `ng-change`)

Answer (score 0):

Use ngBlur to call the following function in the controller and pass x into it

```
var validateName = function (xFromView) {
     if (items.map(function (x) { return x.name }).indexOf(xFromView.name) > -1) {
         xFromView.name = null;
         //Let the user know somehow that their input was invalid
     }
}
```